# Get a subset of random values from an array php

Tags: php, arrays, random

Starting with an array with 10K values.  I want to randomly get 1000 values from it and put them into another array.

Right now, I am using a for loop to get the values, but I want to pick 1000 values and not have to loop 1000 times.  The array_slice function works, but it doesn't give random values.  What is the correct (most efficient) function for this task.

The code right now is

```
$seedkeys = (...array.....);

for ($i=0; $i<1000; $i++) {
        $random = array_rand($seedkeys);  
    $randseed[$i] = $seedkeys[$random];   

}//for close
```

TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, there are a few alternatives.  I'm not sure which is the fastest since you're dealing with a sizable array, but you may want to try them out:

You can use [`shuffle`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php), which will randomize the entire array.  This will likely have the best performance since you're consuming a significant portion of the array (10%).

```
shuffle($seedkeys);
$result = array_slice($seedkeys, 0, 1000);
```

You could use [`array_rand`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) (as you already said) in the manor that Tom Haigh specifies.  This will require copying the keys, so if you're dealing with a significant portion of the source array, this may not be the fastest.  (Note the use of `array_flip`, it's needed to allow the usage of `array_intersect_key`:

```
$keys = array_flip(array_rand($seedkeys, 1000));
$result = array_intersect_key($seedkeys, $keys);
```

If memory is tight, the best solution (besides the MySQL one) would be a loop since it doesn't require arrays to be copied at all.  Note that this will be slower, but if the array contains a lot of information, it may offset the slowness by being more memory efficient (since it only ever copies exactly what it returns)...

```
$result = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
    $result[] = $seedkeys[array_rand($seedkeys)];
}
```

You could do it in MySQL (assuming that the data for the array starts from MySQL).  Be aware this is simple, but not that efficient (See [Jan Kneschke's post](http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/))...

```
SELECT * FROM `foo` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1000;
```

Comment: Thanks maxell, I might have to go with the sql route.  The array size is too big, and it causes memory problems, and the loop was only picking a few repeating keys.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `array_rand()` to get multiple items ?

```
$random_keys = array_rand($seedkeys, 1000);
shuffle($random_keys);
```

This will give you an array of random keys, so to get an array of values you need to do something like this:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($random_keys as $rand_key) {
    $result[] = $seedkeys[$rand_key];
}
```

You could instead use `array_intersect_key()`:

```
$result = array_intersect_key($seedkeys, array_flip($random_keys));
```

Comment: Thanks Tom, the array intersect works as advertised, but only when I have a smaller array, the large arrays return funky repeating values/keys due to memory problem (the same problem as my original loop method).