# Choose 3 different random values from an array

Tags: php, arrays, random

I have an array of 30 values and I need to extract from this array 3 different random values. How can I do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get a subset of random values from an array php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504401/get-a-subset-of-random-values-from-an-array-php)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Shamelessly stolen from the PHP manual:

```
<?php
$input = array("Neo", "Morpheus", "Trinity", "Cypher", "Tank");
$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 2);
echo $input[$rand_keys[0]] . "\n";
echo $input[$rand_keys[1]] . "\n";
?>
```

https://www.php.net/array_rand

Note that, as of PHP 5.2.10, you may want to shuffle (randomize) the keys that are returned via `shuffle($rand_keys)`, otherwise they will always be in order (smallest index first). That is, in the above example, you could get "Neo, Trinity" but never "Trinity, Neo."

If the order of the random elements is not important, then the above code is sufficient.

Answer (score 36):

I'm not sure why bother using `array_rand()` at all as it's just an extra function call for seemingly no reason.  Simply `shuffle()` and slice the first three elements:

```
shuffle($array);
print_r(array_slice($array, 0, 3));
```

Comment: Much much cleaner, this should be an accepted answer

Comment: If `$array` is very big, it might by a performance issue here

Comment: @yunzen - I ran some benchmarks against accepted answer and I agree that `array_slice()` is much slower on very large arrays.  That said, even with 1,000,000 keys it took only 0.124s while `array_rand()` took only 0.004s. For most cases this won't matter but it's good to be aware of!

Answer (score 4):

use `shuffle($array)` then `array_rand($array,3)`

Comment: Any particular reason you're calling `shuffle`?

Comment: just to make sure it is realllllly random :) .. the history behind it is the fact that last year using array_rand i was seeing not-so-random results (similar items on consecutive runs), so to make it a bit more random i would shuffle the array first and then feed to the array_rand function and it seemed to give more random values.