# php loop random product from the list

Tags: php, loops

i have product list, from witch i need to display four items randomly.

```
<?php 

// my product list
function productlistX {
    $array = array( 

        $product {$name = 'product name', $link = 'product link', $img = "product image"};
        $product {$name = 'product name', $link = 'product link', $img = "product image"};
        $product {$name = 'product name', $link = 'product link', $img = "product image"};
        $product {$name = 'product name', $link = 'product link', $img = "product image"};
        $product {$name = 'product name', $link = 'product link', $img = "product image"};
        $product {$name = 'product name', $link = 'product link', $img = "product image"};
        $product {$name = 'product name', $link = 'product link', $img = "product image"};
        $product {$name = 'product name', $link = 'product link', $img = "product image"};
        $product {$name = 'product name', $link = 'product link', $img = "product image"};
        $product {$name = 'product name', $link = 'product link', $img = "product image"};
        $product {$name = 'product name', $link = 'product link', $img = "product image"};
        $product {$name = 'product name', $link = 'product link', $img = "product image"};
        $product {$name = 'product name', $link = 'product link', $img = "product image"};
        $product {$name = 'product name', $link = 'product link', $img = "product image"};
        $product {$name = 'product name', $link = 'product link', $img = "product image"};

    )

    // need to display 4 random products from the array above 
    foreach  {
        echo "<li>".$name . $link . $img . "</li>"
    }
}

// display these random products in my ajax tab (products.php?order=mytab)
$data['mytab'] = $productlistX;

if (isset($data[$_GET['order']])) { 
    echo $data[$_GET['order']];
} 
?>
```

so as you see, i have list ant need to display only four items form the list randomly.

thanks in advance!

Comment: This looks like homework.  You might want to add some more details. Include the code you have tried already.

Comment: updated my question, waiting for help

Comment: Your code is not valid PHP, have you read the manual? You seem to lack knowledge of basic syntax rules of a programming language.

Comment: [Choose 3 different random values from an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945752/choose-3-different-random-values-from-an-array), http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+random+array&submit=search

Comment: yes, i am new in php thats why i am asking for help. 

i need to display several values of $product ($title $link and $image) in random list <li>..</li>, not single values from array ("apple", "dog" ,"cat", ect)

Answer (score 2):

this can be done by php [`rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) function or you can also use the [array_rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) to use the array rand first you need to create the array

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I know what is `text-php` for a file type, but generate four numbers and go for reading until you get all four displayed. Or read the whole thing and select from there.

Comment: sorry, i am new in php. i have updated my question with more details