# random product from the list

Tags: php, list, loops, random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php loop random product from the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464453/php-loop-random-product-from-the-list)

i need product list, from witch i could display 4 items randomly.

i have tried to write php code, but need help with syntax and variables to finish up.

```
<?php 

// my product list
function productlistX {
    $array = array( 

        $product {$name = 'product name', $link = 'product link', $img = "product image"};
        $product {$name = 'product name', $link = 'product link', $img = "product image"};
        $product {$name = 'product name', $link = 'product link', $img = "product image"};
        $product {$name = 'product name', $link = 'product link', $img = "product image"};
        $product {$name = 'product name', $link = 'product link', $img = "product image"};
        $product {$name = 'product name', $link = 'product link', $img = "product image"};
        $product {$name = 'product name', $link = 'product link', $img = "product image"};
        $product {$name = 'product name', $link = 'product link', $img = "product image"};
        $product {$name = 'product name', $link = 'product link', $img = "product image"};
        $product {$name = 'product name', $link = 'product link', $img = "product image"};
        $product {$name = 'product name', $link = 'product link', $img = "product image"};
        $product {$name = 'product name', $link = 'product link', $img = "product image"};
        $product {$name = 'product name', $link = 'product link', $img = "product image"};
        $product {$name = 'product name', $link = 'product link', $img = "product image"};
        $product {$name = 'product name', $link = 'product link', $img = "product image"};

    )

    // need to display 4 random products from the array above 
    foreach  {
        echo "<li>".$name . $link . $img . "</li>"
    }
}

// display these random products in my ajax tab (products.php?order=mytab)
$data['mytab'] = $productlistX;

if (isset($data[$_GET['order']])) { 
    echo $data[$_GET['order']];
} 
?>
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Please don't open duplicate questions, instead, edit your previous one with the code.