# WordPress: Combine two loops with different amount of posts

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to show a random selection of 4 new products in WooCommerce.

For that I'm using a first loop to get the 20 newest products.
Like this:

```
$args= array(
    'post_type'         => 'product',
    'posts_per_page'    => 20,
    'orderby'           => 'date',
);
```

Now I've a second loop to reduce the products to 4 in a random order:

```
$args_new = array(
    'posts_per_page'    => 4,
    'orderby'           => 'rand',
);
```

In the end I merge the two loops:

```
$final_args = array_merge( $args, $args_new );
```

But that doesn't work. Is there any other way to achieve it?

Comment: I don't see any "loops" or other control code here, just 2 arrays which you've stuck together to make one array.

Comment: Do you just want all 24 items in one array? If so, just add them: `$final_args = $args + $args_new`

Comment: @miken32 yes, I didn't add the loops here. But they are there :-)

Comment: @beltouche I want a random selection of 4 new products. Based on a pre-selection of 20 products (4 out of 20).

Comment: A loop is a control structure such as `foreach`. It is not something you "merge". Can you provide some actual code to show what you're doing?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945752/choose-3-different-random-values-from-an-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### General knowledge

---

The `post_type` argument accept `String` or `Array`.

| Argument | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `post_type` | (`String`/`Array`) – use post types. Retrieves posts by post types, default value is `post`. If `tax_query` is set for a query, the default value becomes `any`. |

- Source @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#post-type-parameters

### Merging queries

---

In crude terms we want to combine 2 posts queries, retrieve each posts ID, push them to a new array and open a new query.

Keep in mind that if you want your 4 posts to be random (as you stated in the comments) they might be some duplicates of the last 20 from the first query. Don't forget to offset the second query.

```
<?php

// First query
$args_1 = get_posts( array(
    'post_type' => 'dogs',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_count' => 20,
) );

// Second query
$args_2 = get_posts( array(
    'post_type' => 'dogs',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_count' => 4,
    'offset' => 20,
    'orderby' => RAND,
) );

// Merge queries
$posts = array_merge( $args_1, $args_2 );

// Push posts IDs to new array
$identifiers = array();

foreach ( $posts as $post ) {

  array_push( $identifiers, $post->ID );

};

// Third query
$query = new WP_Query( array(
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'post_count' => 24,
  'post_in' => array_unique( $identifiers ),
) );

var_dump( $query );
```

Comment: Updated to take into account 4 random posts for the second query.