# Retrieving the same value from multiple arrays

Tags: php, arrays, random

so I have two arrays each has 3 values. I need 2 random values ​​from each array.
For example:
From arr1 "red", "blue" and from arr2 "red", "blue".
I need to randomly get the same keys from two arrays. and change the keys every time the page is updated.
If you get keys 1 and 2 from arr1, then from arr2 you should also get keys 1 and 2, or from arr1 3 and 2, and from arr2 also 3 and 2. everything is random.

```
Code:
$arr1 = ['green', 'red', 'blue'];
$arr1 = ['green', 'red', 'blue'];
for ($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++){
echo $arr1[$i];
echo $arr2[$i];
}
```

I don't know how to implement this. I used the shuffle and rand functions but they don't work. shuffle gives incorrect results.

Comment: See [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3945775/2943403) on the dupe target which gives GrumpyCrouton's advice.

Answer (score -1):

If the arrays are always the same length, you could just do something like this. No loop necessary.

```
$arr1 = ['green', 'red', 'blue'];
$arr2 = ['green', 'red', 'blue'];

//get 2 random array keys
$rand_keys = array_rand($arr1, 2);

//get values based on random keys from $arr1
$arr1_random1 = $arr1[$rand_keys[0]];
$arr1_random2 = $arr1[$rand_keys[1]];

//get values based on random keys from $arr2
$arr2_random1 = $arr2[$rand_keys[0]];
$arr2_random2 = $arr2[$rand_keys[1]];
```

If they aren't necessarily the same length, then I don't know how your idea will work, as the arrays may not have the same possible keys.