# Select 2 random elements from associative array

Tags: php, arrays, random

So I have an associative array and I want to return 2 random values from it.
This code only returns 1 array value, which is any of the 4 numbers at random.

```
$array = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4);
$key = array_rand($array); //array_rand($array,2); Putting 2 returns Illegal offset type
$value = $array[$key];
print_r($value); //prints a single random value (ex. 3)
```

How can I return 2 comma separated values from the array values only? Something like 3,4?

Comment: Of course you get the error. If you pass a second argument, you get an array of keys (as described in the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php)), which is not a valid index. http://codepad.org/Maf1EarJ

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get a subset of random values from an array php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504401/get-a-subset-of-random-values-from-an-array-php) and [many, many other questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+get+n+random+elements+from+array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab the keys from the array with [`array_keys()`](http://www.php.net/array_keys), shuffle the keys with [`shuffle()`](http://www.php.net/shuffle), and print out the values corresponding to the first two keys in the shuffled keys array, like so:

```
$array = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4);
$keys = array_keys( $array);
shuffle( $keys);
echo $array[ $keys[0] ] . ',' . $array[ $keys[1] ];
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/E54w0u)

Or, you can use [`array_rand()`](http://www.php.net/array_rand)'s second parameter to grab two keys, like so:

```
$array = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4);
$keys = array_rand( $array, 2);
echo $array[ $keys[0] ] . ',' . $array[ $keys[1] ];
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/qDFoff)

Comment: Going with this one as it was the quickest and works flawlessly!

Answer (score 5):

`array_rand` takes an additional optional parameter which specifies how many random entries you want out of the array.

```
$input_array = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4);
$rand_keys = array_rand($input_array, 2);
echo $input_array[$rand_keys[0]] . ',' . $input_array[$rand_keys[1]];
```

Check the PHP documentation for array_rand [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php).

Comment: 1. You have an extra parenthesis at the end of the 3rd line, and 2. This will only select 2 random keys, not the values from the original array.

Comment: @Jeshurun Thanks for the help:) But nickb posted first correctly, both very good answers!

Answer (score 0):

There is a more efficient approach that preserves keys and values.

```
function shuffle_assoc(&$array) {
        $keys = array_keys($array);

        shuffle($keys);

        foreach($keys as $key) {
            $new[$key] = $array[$key];
        }

        $array = $new;

        return true;
    }
```

Check the documentation [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php#94697)

Answer (score -1):

```
$a=rand(0,sizeof($array));
$b=$a;
while ($a==$b) $b=rand(0,sizeof($array));

$ar=array_values($array);
$element1=$ar[$a];
$element2=$ar[$b];
```

Should be more efficient than `shuffle()` and freinds, if the array is large.

Comment: `array_rand` should be efficient, though.

Comment: Should be - I just didn't have it at hand!